# How to make field in admin panel required

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend, backend, validation

In admin panel on creating order page, i need to set field Middle Name/Initial required, if chosen shipping method is "Free shipping", otherwise, this field doesn`t need to be required. Also, is this possible on backend?